# C++: What is the "<>" in std :: less<>

Tags: c++, templates, stl

As the title says. I don't know what the `<>` does in the `std::less<>`

For example, I have seen it in templates like this:

```
template <typename T, typename C = std::less<>>
```

and like this as well:

```
template <typename T, typename C = std::less<T>>
```

What is the difference?

Comment: It means in the first case the default template argument will be used for `std::less` while in the second case you're explicitly passing `T` as the template argument.

Comment: When used with `std::set` and `std::map`, `less<>` (aka `less<void>`) enables some extra perks. Look up "transparent comparators".